# Install Arcreader to ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, gis

I try to install [Arcreader](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcreader) to ubuntu 12.10 64bit. But I have some errors during installing the program. It finished istallation but it doesnent work in 64 bit system (ArcReader is not properly installed). from requirements of program I can install only in redHat and SUSE.

from ESRI:

> ArcReader is a free, easy-to-use desktop mapping application that allows users to view, explore, and print maps and globes. Anyone with ArcReader can view high-quality interactive maps authored by a high-level ArcGIS for Desktop product and published with the ArcGIS Publisher extension.

Images of Error's

[image: error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 2):

For the `/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3 was not found`

1) Get the libgfortran from command line.

`apt-get install libgfortran3`

2) Once downloaded, located the libgfortran and create a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/`

```
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3
```

[You have to find where the libgfortran was downloaded, mine was in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/]

3) Install again ArcReader

Cheers!